# Python socket stream how control if the device is online?

Tags: python, sockets

in a stream socket in python, how i can check if the device is online and alive?

Here it's an example:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9876
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096
videofile = "videos/royalty-free_footage_wien_18_640x360.mp4"

bytes = open(videofile).read()

print len(bytes)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

client.sendall(bytes) # ---> Here i have to check if the device it's online

client.close()
```

This type of check it's very important to me, because, if the device it's not online, i have to retry the entire transmission in order to not lose the data.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't connect via TCP if the server isn't listening, so if connect worked, it's online.

Comment: This looks like a file transfer. Is it not possible to use something higher level and custom built for the purpose like rsync or sftp?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is TCP, if the remote end is down the connect call should raise an exception like `ConnectionRefusedError`. You can catch that and do what's necessary.

Comment: I know, but, suppose that the remote endpoint it will connect, and in the middle of the file transfer i'll shutdown that, how i can retry the transfer?

Comment: You have to design a protocol to do this. Send your data piece by piece with some kind of acknowledgement from the remote end about how much has been received. `sendall` is just a loop that will repeatedly call `send` to send all the data. It's not possible to say how much was sent in case of a failure. This is why I suggested that you use a proper file transfer protocol and tool.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, the other endpoint accepts only a socket stream and nothing else.

Even if i try to call .recv(4) i'll not get any response

Comment: Do you have control over the server on the other end?